# Tensorflow Gdb line numbers

Tags: debugging, tensorflow, gdb

I am creating a new Platform/Device for Tensorflow.
I have registered my Platform and right now am developing an Operation.
As it happens in development i am getting a crash and am trying to debug it with gdb.
The issue is that although i have added flags in bazel to generate the debug version of tensorflow, gdb does not show file/line numbers in the backtrace, nor can i see variables and code:

```
#0  0x00007fffe288d7f4 in tensorflow::Tensor::DebugString(int) const () from /tmp/TensorflowVT/vt_tf/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/../libtensorflow_framework.so
#1  0x00007fffe4cd1373 in ConstOp::Compute(tensorflow::OpKernelContext*) () from /tmp/TensorflowVT/vt_tf/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so
#2  0x00007fffe2a9ab4d in tensorflow::(anonymous namespace)::ExecutorState::Process(tensorflow::(anonymous namespace)::ExecutorState::TaggedNode, long long) () from /tmp/TensorflowVT/vt_tf/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/../libtensorflow_framework.so
```

I am building tensorflow like this:

```
 bazel build --incompatible_remove_native_http_archive=false --incompatible_package_name_is_a_function=false --config=opt --verbose_failures --compilation_mode=dbg -c dbg --strip=never //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

I also tried manualy finding the crash point, and added debug prints in 
*tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.cc*, but

Is it possible to get file/lines and annotated code, to better understand where and why i get the crash?

Comment: What is in your `~/.bazelrc`? What happens if you remove `--config=opt`?

Comment: @EmployedRussian 
I do not have a ~/.bazelrc.
I also tried building with the '--config=opt' option removed, but it did not change any thing in the gdb backtrace.

I also run file on libtensorflow_framework.so to verify it is not striped:

```
/libtensorflow_framework.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=00c18ac670963e0b0e00e5dac407da20451461ed, not stripped
```